# PHPUNIT (Проверить массив)

Tags: php, массивы, phpunit

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно проверить вернулся пустой массив или нет.

У меня есть метод, который возвращает массив

```
<?php
namespace practice\Model;

class SendValidate
{
    public function checkSend($email, $text)
    {
        $message_about_send = array("", "");

        if ($email == "") {
            $message_about_send[0] = "Field email empty";
        }

        if ($text == "") {
            $message_about_send[1] = "Field message empty";
        }

        return json_encode($message_about_send);
    }
}
```

И вот код с тестом

```
<?php

namespace practice\Model;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class SendValidateTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testCheckSend()
    {
        $obj = new SendValidate();
        $this->assertEmpty($obj->checkSend('', ''));
    }
}
```

Какой функцией можно в тестах проверить какой массив вернулся, пустой или нет.

Comment: У вас джсон-строка возвращается, а не массив.

Comment: Как можно проверить этот возврат в PHPUNIT ?
Пуст ли json

Comment: Возьмите пустой массив, закодируйте его в джсон и сравните с результатом функции.

Comment: Я понимаю что нужно сделать.
Как проверить пустой ли массив в PHPUNIT?

Есть assertEquals, assertTrue ...

Какой функцией проверяется массив?

Comment: Вы понимаете что ваша функция возвращает __строку__, а не массив?

Comment: ПОнял, как проверить в PHPUNIT возвращается пустая строка или нет?

Comment: Вам не возвращается пустая строка. Если вы не можете понять что возвращает функция и как проверить результаты - запустите функцию с разными наборами аргументов, посмотрите на возвращаемые значения и перенесите их в тест.

Comment: Разобрался, вопрос закрыт

Comment: Можете сами ответить на собственный вопрос, ежели разобрались.